# QT QTableView get checked items

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qcheckbox

I have a QTableView with check boxes was created by:

```
 QStandardItem* checkBox = new QStandardItem(true);
 checkBox->setCheckable(true);
 checkBox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
 model->setItem(row, 0, checkBox);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

Now I want to get all the **chceked** rows. As I found in many samples code I have to write something like this:

```
 QItemSelectionModel *select = ui->tableView->selectionModel();
 QModelIndexList selectedSensosrs = select->selectedRows();
 for(int i = 0; i < selectedSensosrs.count(); i++)
 {
            //do something
  }
```

But this code doesn't work, the count value is zero even I checked a few items!!
I looked a lot for a better way to dothat, but didn't find...:(

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight misconception on your side. Selected rows is not a row, which contains a selected checkbox, but a row, which is highlighted. I am afraid you must iterate through all your cells and query the QCheckState.